# How to make clickable overlay activity android?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing Android lock screen. And I need my lock screen activity be over everything in Android.

Here is the code for overlaying:

```
params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT ,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
  | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    PixelFormat.RGB_888);

wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

mTopView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lock_screen, null);
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
wm.addView(mTopView, params);
```

It overlays great. **BUT** it freezes everything. I set `onButtonCLiclListener` on button, but it doesn't work. Where am I wrong? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by *freeze everything*? Does the phone become inaccessible (even via ADB) or just the UI completely unresponsive? The latter is to be expected, as all pointer events go to your activity. Also, why are you changing both the window attributes of your current window and add a new overlay view with the same attributes?

Comment: UI almost unresponsive. Buttons are clicable, but doesn't work. I set text on a textview, but text doesn't appear.

Comment: Do you set the `OnClickListener` programmatically or within the layout XML? Because the layout you are inflating is not attached to the activity, it is attached to its own top-level window. Also --as noted-- you've got two top-level windows active: The one the activity is in and the one the inflated view from `R.layout.lock_screen` is in.

Comment: @dhke I set it programmatically. How can I manupilate infated layout?

Comment: `mTopView` has `findViewById()`. Use that to obtain references to your button objects (children of `mTopView`) by their id and attach `OnClickListener's. You should also be able to drop the `getWindow().setAttributes()` line.